# Помогите отредактировать регулярное выражение

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, powershell

Здравствуйте!

На MSDN нашёл регулярное выражение, наиболее мне подходящее. Но пытаясь его подстроить под себя, столкнулся с проблемой, что оно начинает выдавать неожиданные результаты.

Пример ниже. Нужно выхватить из текста фрагмент {mno...} внутри может быть неограниченное количество вложений.

```
$content = "{abc}{mno{xyz}}"
$mask = "[^{}]*" + 
        "(" +
        "((?'Open'\{)[^{}]*)+" +
        "((?'Close-Open'\})[^{}]*)+" + 
        ")*" +
        "(?(Open)(?!))"

$date = [Datetime]::Now

$match = [Regex]::Match($content, $mask)
if ($match.Success)
{
    $grp = 0
    $match.Groups |
    %{
        ("Group {0} : {1}" -f $grp++, $_.Value)
        $cap = 0
        $_.Captures |
        %{
            ("`tCapture {0}: {1}" -f $cap++, $_.Value)
        }
    }
}

([Datetime]::Now - $date).ToString("hh\:mm\:ss")


#Group 0 : {abc}{mno{xyz}}
#   Capture 0: {abc}{mno{xyz}}
#Group 1 : {mno{xyz}}
#   Capture 0: {abc}
#   Capture 1: {mno{xyz}}
#Group 2 : {xyz
#   Capture 0: {abc
#   Capture 1: {mno
#   Capture 2: {xyz
#Group 3 : }
#   Capture 0: }
#   Capture 1: }
#   Capture 2: }
#Group 4 : 
#Group 5 : mno{xyz}
#   Capture 0: abc
#   Capture 1: xyz
#   Capture 2: mno{xyz}
```

Пробовал маску менять

```
 $mask = "[^{}]*" + 
        "(" +
        "((?'Open'\{)mno[^{}]*)+" +
        "((?'Close-Open'\})[^{}]*)+" + 
        ")*" +
        "(?(Open)(?!))"
```

но получается вообще фигня

Comment: Вот такое выражение должно подойти: `$mask = "[^{}]+{((?>[^{}]+|{(?<c>)|}(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!)))}"`

Comment: @stribizhev, Что-то здесь не то со скобками... Вроде {} заэкранировал, а всеравно ругается...

Comment: Не надо ничего экранировать, у меня на консоли выводится `Group 0 : mno{xyz}//
        Capture 0: mno{xyz}//
Group 1 : xyz//
        Capture 0: xyz//
Group 2 :`

Comment: А какой результат Вам нужен?

Comment: @stribizhev, необходимо выхватить результат от {mno до } относящейся к ней. дело в том, что может быть несколько вложений и встречаться несколько таких групп...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текущее регулярное выражение содержит подшаблон `(((?'Open'\{)[^{}]*)+((?'Close-Open'\})[^{}]*)+)*(?(Open)(?!))`, в котором есть 3 неименные и 2 именные захватывающие подмаски:

```
(                 # 1-ая неименная подмаска 
 (                # 2-ая неименная подмаска 
   (?'Open'\{)    # 1-ая именная подмаска
   [^{}]*
 )+
 (                    # 3-ая неименная подмаска
   (?'Close-Open'\})  # 2-ая именная подмаска
    [^{}]*
 )+
)*
(?(Open)(?!))
```

Поэтому в результате получаем 5 групп.

Если надо получить только текст во второй подстроке в фигурных скобках, можно воспользоваться следующим регулярным выражением и кодом:

```
$content = "{abc}{mno{xy{z}}}"
$mask = "(?<!^){((?>[^{}]+|{(?<c>)|}(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!)))}"
$match = [Regex]::Match($content, $mask)
if ($match.Success)
    {$match.Groups[1].Value}
```

Результат: `mno{xy{z}}` (при входной строке `{abc}{mno{xy{z}}}`)

[Демо регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5E)%7B((%3F%3E%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2B%7C%7B(%3F%3Cc%3E)%7C%7D(%3F%3C-c%3E))*(%3F(c)(%3F!)))%7D&i=%7Babc%7D%7Bmno%7Bxy%7Bz%7D%7D%7D)

В регулярном выражении `(?<!^)` блок предварительного предшествующего просмотра, который обеспечивает совпадение внутри строки, не в ее начале, а `{((?>[^{}]+|{(?<c>)|}(?<-c>))*(?(c)(?!)))}` находит подстроку от первой открывающией фигурной скобки до соответствующей ей закрывающей.